# Checking current checked boxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am attempting to make it so upon click it checks three rules as follows:

1. If everything is unchecked check the "All" checkbox.
2. If "All" checkbox is seleceted then uncheck everything else.
3. If a console is checked (at least one of them) then do neither of the above.

Unfortunately it only loops through once and stops working and never fills any of the other requirements. Could someone inform me what I am missing?

Thank you for your assistance.

```js
$('#platform-container').click(function() {
 if((`input[type=checkbox][name=platform]:checked`).length > 0){
  $('#platform-all').attr("checked", status)
 }
 else if($('#platform-all').is(':checked')){
  $('.single').attr("unchecked", status)
 }
 else{
  $('.single').is(':checked')
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-styles platforms-list">
  <button id="platform-button" class="button">
     Platforms
    </button>
  <form id="platform-container" class="param-container">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="platform-all" class="platform" name="platform" value="4,18,1,5,6,7,8" />
      <label for="platform">All</label
                        >
                    </div>

     <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-switch"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
                            value="7"
                                   checked="true"
      />
      <label for="platform-switch"
       >Nintendo Switch</label
      >
     </div>

     <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-ps4"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="18"
      />
      <label for="platform-ps4"
       >Playstation 4</label
      >
     </div>

     <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-xb1"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="1"
      />
      <label for="platform-xb1"
       >Xbox One</label
      >
     </div>

     <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-3ds"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="8"
      />
      <label for="platform-3ds"
       >Nintendo 3DS</label
      >
     </div>

     <div class="checkbox-container">
      <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-pcMasterRace"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="4"
      />
      <label for="platform-pc"
       >PC</label
      >
     </div>

                    <div class="checkbox-container">
     <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-linux"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="6"
     />
     <label for="platform-linux"
      >Linux</label
                    >
                    </div>

                    <div class="checkbox-container">
     <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-mac"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="5"
     />
     <label for="platform-mac">Mac</label>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the adding then removing of lorem lipsum. It kept telling me I didn't give enough detail but edited out it's fine...?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with the code which prevent you to achieve what you planned:

- When you have multiple inputs with the same name, you should treat the name as an array item, in your case `name="platform[]"`, or else any newer input will just override the previous one's value.
- The third option in your `if else` (`$('.single').is(':checked')`) conditions is doing nothing, all it does is returning a boolean, not really changing any value.
- What is `status` in your code? It looks like an undefined var which will do nothing and break the code as well.

Comment: I'm new to coding and I am self-taught. I learned that you should put status in it??? Not sure what it did. But thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check both snippet, if anyone helps your problem. Else leave a comment.

```js
$('#platform-all').off().on('click', function() {
    $('#platform-container').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});

$('.single').off().on('click', function() {
    let totalItem = $('.single.platform').length;
    let totalCheckedItem = $('.single[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    $('#platform-all').prop('checked', !totalItem == totalCheckedItem);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-styles platforms-list">
 <button id="platform-button" class="button">
     Platforms
    </button>
 <form id="platform-container" class="param-container">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input type="checkbox" id="platform-all" class="platform" name="platform" value="4,18,1,5,6,7,8" />
   <label for="platform-all">All</label
                        >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-switch"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
                            value="7"
                                   checked="true"
      />
   <label for="platform-switch"
       >Nintendo Switch</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-ps4"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="18"
      />
   <label for="platform-ps4"
       >Playstation 4</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-xb1"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="1"
      />
   <label for="platform-xb1"
       >Xbox One</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-3ds"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="8"
      />
   <label for="platform-3ds"
       >Nintendo 3DS</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-pcMasterRace"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="4"
      />
   <label for="platform-pc"
       >PC</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-linux"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="6"
     />
   <label for="platform-linux">Linux</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-mac"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="5"
     />
   <label for="platform-mac">Mac</label>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

```js
$('#platform-all').off().on('click', function() {
    $('#platform-container').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

$('.single').off().on('click', function() {
    let totalItem = $('.single.platform').length;
    let totalCheckedItem = $('.single[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    $('#platform-all').prop('checked', totalItem === totalCheckedItem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-styles platforms-list">
 <button id="platform-button" class="button">
     Platforms
    </button>
 <form id="platform-container" class="param-container">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input type="checkbox" id="platform-all" class="platform" name="platform" value="4,18,1,5,6,7,8" />
   <label for="platform-all">All</label
                        >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-switch"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
                            value="7"
                                   checked="true"
      />
   <label for="platform-switch"
       >Nintendo Switch</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-ps4"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="18"
      />
   <label for="platform-ps4"
       >Playstation 4</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-xb1"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="1"
      />
   <label for="platform-xb1"
       >Xbox One</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-3ds"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="8"
      />
   <label for="platform-3ds"
       >Nintendo 3DS</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
       type="checkbox"
       id="platform-pcMasterRace"
       class="single platform"
       name="platform"
       value="4"
      />
   <label for="platform-pc"
       >PC</label
      >
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-linux"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="6"
     />
   <label for="platform-linux">Linux</label>
                    
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
   <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="platform-mac"
      class="single platform"
      name="platform"
      value="5"
     />
   <label for="platform-mac">Mac</label>
 </div>
  </form>
  </div>
```